# Як правильно вживати прикметник "вірний"?

Tags: вживання-слів, розмовна-українська

В мережі є багато інформації стосовно даного питання, але як все-таки правильно вживати вказаний прикметник?

[image]
Зображення з сайту [Мова — ДНК нації](http://ukr-mova.in.ua/library/sunonimu/virniy)

*яка відповідь є вірною?*
*вірно сказано*
*вірний друг*
*вірний шлях*
*вірна дружина*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## На захист усієї множини значень слова «вірний»

На [цій сторінці](//ua-etymology.livejournal.com/58465.html) користувач maksymus (засновник спільноти ua_etymology і деяких інших спільнот про українську мову) достатньо переконливо (на мою думку) доводить недоречність спроб збіднити множину значень слова «вірний».

- Вже в XI ст. (в старослов’янські пам’ятки) знаходимо вжиток слова «вѣрьнъ» у значенні «’αξιόπιστος, достовірний, правильний», а також «вѣрьно» у значенні точно.
- У XIII — XIV ст (давньокиївський період) «вѣрьныи» зустрічається у збірках у значенні «правильний, істинний», наприклад:

  > рѣшенье нѣ(с) вѣрно
  >   вѣрно бо слово
- У 1886 бачимо такі переклади сліва «вірний» і «вірність» у [«Малоруско-нїмецкому словарі» Желехівського](http://litopys.org.ua/djvu/zheleh_slovnyk.htm):

  > Ві́рний, *a[dhectivum]*. glaubig; 2) true; 3) **richtig**.
  >
  > <…>
  >
  > Ві́рність, -ости *f[emininum (substantivum)]*. Treue; 2) **Richtigkeit**.

Раптове зникнення значення «правильний» у слова «вірний» напочатку XX століття після дев'яти століть його існування видається малоймовірним.

P. S.: А ще деякі пуристи вважають, що в українській мові, навпаки, немає слів «правильний» і «правильно», бо в «Словарі» Грінченка їх немає, лише «[вірний](http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/7621-virnyj.html#show_point)» (зверніть увагу на значення 2 — «истинный, дѣйствительный») — але це вже, на мою думку, інша хибна надмірність.

## Офіційна позиція

При цьому я не можу не зазначити, що в [«Словник української мови» в 11 томах 1970-х років](http://sum.in.ua/s/virnyj), а разом з ним і [«Словник української мови» в 20 томах 2010-х років](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=14678&page=477) подає в слові «вірний» значення 2 «те саме, що [пра́вильний](http://sum.in.ua/s/pravyljnyj) 1» з помітами «**розм[овне]**» і «**рідко[вживане]**». Оскільки останній словник виданий під егідою Українського мовно-інформаційного фонду Національної академії наук України, є порівняно сучасним і не суперечить іншим виданим ними словникам, то це можна вважати їхньою офіційною позицією. З якою я особисто, однак, не погоджуюсь.

Answer (score 5):

Колись пан [@Sasha](/users/4/) вказав на ось таку [ланку-обговору](http://ua-etymology.livejournal.com/58465.html) пана Максима, яка на штиб «проти пуризму» і де:

Просить поглянути на наступні етимолоґічні словники.

[ЕС Фасмера 1, сторінки: 292—293](http://starling.rinet.ru/cgi-bin/response.cgi?root=config&morpho=0&basename=%5Cdata%5Cie%5Cvasmer&first=1&text_word=%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0&method_word=substring&ww_word=on&text_general=&method_general=substring&text_origin=&method_origin=substring&text_trubachev=&method_trubachev=substring&text_editorial=&method_editorial=substring&text_pages=&method_pages=substring&text_any=&method_any=substring&sort=word)

> **ве́ра**,
>
> *ве́рить*, укр. *вíра*, др.-русск., ст.-слав. вѣра πίστις (Супр., Клоц.), болг. *вя́ра*, сербохорв. Bjȅpa, словен. véra, чеш. víra, польск. wiara, в.-луж., н.-луж. wjera.
>
> Родственно авест. var- "верить", varǝna- "вера", осет. urnyn "верить"; см. Мейе, Et. 169. Далее, вероятно, сюда же д.-в.-н. wâra ж. "правда, верность, милость", др.-исл. vár "обет, торжественное обещание", д.-в.-н. wâr "правдивый, верный", др.-ирл. fír "правдивый, истинный", лат. vērus "истинный, правдивый", гот. tuzwērjan "сомневаться", unwērjan "досадовать"; см. Уленбек, Aind. Wb. 293; Торп 395; Траутман, BSW 351; Педерсен, Kelt. Gr. 1, 50; Вальде 825.

ЕСУМ, том 1, сторінка 402

> **віра¹** «довірʼя, впевненість; релігія», *вір* (у виразі *брати на вір* «на віру»), *віри́тель* «кредитор», *ві́рник* «довірена особа; [парафіянин ВеУг]» [*вірня́нка*] «вірна дружина», [*віру́тник*] «вірник», *ві́рщик*, [*вірʼя́н*] «сват», [*ві́рисний*] «імовірний, вірогідний» Ж, *ві́рний*, [*віру́тний*] «дійсний, справжній», *ві́рчий, ві́рити, ві́рувати, ві́рую* «credo», *безві́рник, безві́рʼя, дові́ра, дові́рливий, довіря́ти, достові́рний,* [*запові́рити*] «ввірити» Ж, [*зві́рість*] «звірка», [*зві́рки*] Ж, *зві́рник, звіря́ти, звіря́тися́, зневі́ра, зневі́рʼя, зневі́ритися, неві́ра, неві́рник, неві́рство, неві́рʼя,* [*недові́р*] «недовірʼя»; недовірок» Ж, *недо́вірок, недові́рʼя, недові́ркуватий, недові́рливий, пере́вірка, переві́рник, перевіря́ти, пові́рка, пові́рник, пові́рʼя, пові́рити, прові́рка, провіря́ти, сповіря́ти, спроневі́ритися, уві́ритися*;
>
> російська, білоруська, македонська *ве́ра*, давньоруська *вѣра*, польська wiara, чеська víra, совацька viera, верхньолужицько, нижньолужицька wěra, болгарська *вя́ра*, сербохорватська *вјěра*, словенська véra, старословʼянська **вѣра**;
>
> прасловʼянська věra < *vēra;
>
> споріднене з авестійська var- «вірити», varəna- «віра», осетинська urnyn «вірити», готська tuzwērjan «сумніватися», давньоісландська vár «обіцянка», давньоверхньонімецька wâra «правда, вірність, милість», середньоверхньонімецька wār «дійсний, справжній», нововерхньонімецька wahr (те саме), латинська vērus «дійсний, справжній, істинний», ірландська fir «вірний»; індоєвропейська *u̯ēr- «справжній».
>
> Шанский ЭСРЯ 1 3, 53—54; Фасмер 1 292—293; Преобр. 1 101; Brückner 611; Machek ESJČ 690—691; БЕР 1 217—218; Стоянов 42; Skok 3 602—603; Pokorny 1165–1166.

Наголошує, що така помилка через недодавання до наступного словника словника «вірний».

[Російсько-український академічний словник 1924–33рр. (А. Кримський, С. Єфремов), сторінка 62](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&scope=rusb&dicts=1)

> **Ве́рный**
>
> **1)** ві́рний, пе́вний, незра́дний, наді́йний. *[Двох що-найвірні́ших слуг кли́че. Він пе́вна люди́на. Ма́ю пе́вну схо́ванку, там ніхто́ не зна́йде]*.
>
> - **В.** *слову* – на сло́во ві́рний.
> - **Ве́рным** *оставаться кому* – держа́тися кого́;
>
> **2)** (*точный, правильный*) пе́вний, справедли́вий, правди́вий. *[Справедли́ва ува́га. У кооперати́вній крамни́ці вага́ справедли́ва (правди́ва)]*.
>
> - *Указать* **ве́рный** *путь* – показа́ти правди́вий шлях.
> - **Ве́рный** *оригиналу* – згі́дний з перво́писом;
>
> 3) (*обеспеченный*) безпе́чний, безпе́чен. *[Приї́деш зве́чора – вече́ронька безпе́чная. Його́ ша́нси були́ вже безпе́чні].*

Зазначає, що слово за совітські часи значення «правильний» вернули до словників на шкоду иншим, з чим треба теж боротися і наводить наступне:

[«Як ми говоримо» Бориса Антоненка-Давидовича](http://yak-my-hovorymo.wikidot.com/virnyj-pravdyvyj-pravylnyj-pevnyj-slushnyj)

> **Вірний, правдивий, правильний, певний, слушний**
>
> Прикметник *вірний* і прислівник *вірно* з якогось часу не тільки витискають з ужитку інші, більш відповідні слова, а й набирають невластивого їм значення. Не тільки в діловій мові, а й у сучасних художніх творах ми часто натрапляємо на ці слова в значенні «правильний, певний»: «Учинити напад на аеродром — це все одно, що повести на *вірну* загибель сотню бійців»; «Дрімлюга знайшов *вірний* шлях»; «Ти стоїш на *вірній* дорозі»; «Сама глибинами серця відчувала — *вірно* робить син».
>
> А тим часом в українській класиці й фольклорі цих слів уживали в далеко вужчому значенні, надаючи їм поняття тільки відданості: «Ой вийди, вийди, дівчино моя *вірная*» (народна пісня); «Без *вірного* друга великая туга» (прислів’я); «Хто *вірно* кохає, той часто вітає» (М. Номис).
>
> Якщо в фразі йдеться не про відданість, а про правильність, слушність, правдивість, тоді треба вдаватись до інших прикметників і прислівників: «А щоб *певна* була правда, — нехай шлях покаже» (Т. Шевченко); «Землі своєї зелень і блакить любив я серцем і на схилі віку хотів про це *правдиво* повістить» (М. Рильський); «Не раз, заблудившись, навмання йшли мандрівники тайгою, намагаючись знайти *правильний* напрям» (О. Донченко); «Надія теж не докучала розпитами. Також відкладала до *слушного* вільнішого часу» (Я. Баш); «Сьорбаючи чай, Артем чекав на *слушну* хвилину…» (А. Головко).
>
> З цих прикладів само собою випливає, що в наведених на початку фразах слід було написати: «на *певну* загибель», «*правдивий* шлях», «на *правильній* (на *правдивій*) дорозі», «*слушно* робить син».
>
> Іноді поряд із прикметниками *правильний*, *поправний* уживають і прикметника *вірний* у таких висловах: *вірний* переклад, *вірний* рисунок (малюнок), цебто — відповідний оригіналу, натурі, точний (Словник за редакцією А. Кримського).

І пише на кінець: *сучасні* словники ради не знають і знов схиляються до пуризму, дадаючи примітку *розм.* (зі вказівкою на словника):

[Словник української мови: в 11 томах. — Том 1, **1970**. — Стор. 680.](http://sum.in.ua/s/virnyj)

> **2.** *розм., рідко.* Те саме, що **правильний**
>
> 1; правдивий, точний.
>
> *А шлях наш — вірний, бо це — шлях, до якого рано чи пізно неминуче прийдуть і всі інші країни* (Ленін, 33, 1951, 131); — *Краще давай я постукаю і послухаю тебе, і тоді ми поставимо вірний діагноз* (Оксана Іваненко, Великі очі, 1956, 35).

---

**По-перше,** пуризм — це [не щось погане](https://r2u.org.ua/node/45).

**По-друге,** не згадали: існує старіший словник без згадки *правильний*.

[Словарь української мови 1909р. (Б. Грінченко)](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9&scope=ukr&dicts=12)

> **Ві́рний**, **-а**, **-е**. Вѣрный, преданный.
>
> *Ой вийди, вийди, дівчинонько моя вірная.* Мет. 81. *Ночує ніченьку з вірною дружиною.* Нп. *Без вірного друга великая туга.* Ном. № 9021. *Прошу тебе, милий, вірними словами.* Мет. 47.
>
> **2)** Истинный, дѣйствительный.
>
> **3)** Правовѣрный. 
>   *Прохало два вірних одного невірного: дай нам те, що лучче царства небесного.* Ном., стр. 290, № 3.
>
> Ум. **Вірне́нький**, **вірне́сенький**.

**По-третє,** це цілком нормально, коли найперше значення не цілком відповідає сучасному. Ба, таке і з [правильний](http://starling.rinet.ru/cgi-bin/response.cgi?root=/usr/local/share/starling/morpho&morpho=1&basename=morpho%5Cvasmer%5Cvasmer&first=1&off=&text_word=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%CC%81%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9&method_word=substring&ic_word=on&text_general=&method_general=substring&ic_general=on&text_origin=&method_origin=substring&ic_origin=on&text_trubachev=&method_trubachev=substring&ic_trubachev=on&text_editorial=&method_editorial=substring&ic_editorial=on&text_pages=&method_pages=substring&ic_pages=on&text_any=&method_any=substring&sort=word&ic_any=on) (по тому ж Фасмеру).

Особливо коли…

**По-четверте**, рідко буває двох цілком замінних слів (коли не враховувати нові чи явні запозичення, чого не сказати про тут), бо словам притамана «забарвленість». До слова *вірний* → *віра*; *правильний* → *правда*, *право*;

**Тому!** Бажано вживати ясні слова, коли не бажаєте плутати читача чи слухача. І цьому підкреслюють «пуристи».

*Вірні слова*, *вірна відповідь* — це коли *[належно](http://sum.in.ua/s/nalezhnyj)*, особливо коли *до* в*подоби*. Порівняйте до «*ваша* правда».

А *правильна відповідь* на, наприклад, уроках.

---

Зауваження до [відповіді](/a/3000/585) пана [@Sasha](/users/4/)

Було би непогано додати значення иншого слова з старого словника Желехівського, сторінка 732

> **Правильний** *f* regelmäßig, gesetzmäßig, richtig.
>
> **Правильність** Regelmäßigkeit, Gesetzmäßigkeit, **Correctheit**.

Відчувається відміність і жорсткість. Не дивно, бо подібна ріжниця існує між [**right** та **correct**](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/1730/226239) чи [**korrekt** та **richtig**](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/38264/). Слова *regelmäßig* (константа), *gesetzmäßig (правомірно, по закону)* вже самі по собі жорсткі.

**Коротко.** Сorrect — правильно і «не обговорюється»; Right — правильно по моралі чи просто думки (коли до вподоби).

Answer (score 3):

http://sum.in.ua/s/virnyj
Є один з багатьох прикладів, вірний означає постійний в своїх поглядах відданий.
Вірний своїй нареченій, бути вірним своїй державі. прикладів може бути багато.